# Parsing text file for certain content

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, data-scrubbing

I am trying to parse a dynamic html page where the content of "price" will be changing.

How can I parse the page and get the price value? I will be running the script every 30 seconds to see if there is a change in price.

```
"*className*" : "DealService.model.Price",
              "price" : "93.52"
```

That is the snippit of code I need to parse. Where "93.52" will be changing.

How can I get the value of the price stored in a variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So are you parsing html, or plain text? Perhaps show a complete file

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
preg_match('/"price"\s:\s"(.*)"/', $input, $output);
if(!empty($output[1]))
    $price = $output[1];
```